# I only want to print the table names from my DB

Tags: mysql, perl

Here is my code. I get an internal server error with this. The subroutine is a clone from a book. So it is good to go. I just cannot get these tables to be on the screen by the time I look at the site. Is there anything that you guys see I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use 5.010;
use DBI;    #this is for database connections.

use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

#my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "myown";
my $hostname = "whereitis";
my $dsn      = "longblabla";
my $userid   = "memyselfandI";
my $password = "onlymetoknow";
my $page1    = "Tables in the database: " . $database;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;

print
    header,
    start_html(
        -title => $page1,
        -meta => {
            'viewport'  => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
            'copyright' => 'copyright 2015 Noel Villaman'
        },
        -style => [
            { -src => 'bootstrap.min.css' },
            { -src => 'cgicssjs/style1.css' }
        ]
    ),
    h1( $page1 ),
    div( table_names( $dbh->table_info() ) ),
    hr,
    "\n";

# Disconnect from the database.
$dbh->disconnect();
print end_html;

sub table_names {
    my $names = $_[0];

    ### Create a new statement handle to fetch table information
    my $tabsth = $names;    #$dbh->table_info();

    ### Print the header
    print "<h1>Table Name</h1>";
    print "<h3>===============</h3>";

    ### Iterate through all the tables...
    while ( my ( $qual, $owner, $name, $type, $remarks ) = $tabsth->fetchrow_array() ) {

        ### Tidy up NULL fields
        foreach ( $qual, $owner, $name, $type, $remarks ) {
            $_ = "N/A" unless defined $_;
        }

        ### Print out the table metadata...
        print "<h3>$name</h3>";
    }

    exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error please?

Comment: It does not show on the screen. It only states 500 Internal Server Error Contact your bla bla bla....

Comment: And what does the server log show?

Comment: It is my school server, so I don't think I can get there. Can I?

Comment: Does this program work when you run it from the command line?

Comment: No, it does not run from the command line. I gives me error saying that the terminal cannot connect to the server at line 3. But if I comment out the subroutine, everything is cool. http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/~villaman/tablessql.cgi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment, you say that you don't think that you can see the web server error log. It is ridiculous to try to develop a CGI program without access to the server error log. You should try to get that fixed as a matter of urgency.

But in the mean time, you can work round this restriction by adding the following near the top of your code.

```
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
```

That will copy the error log messages to your browser so you can see them. But remember to remove or comment out that line before the code goes into production (not that this code will ever go into production in any meaningful way - I realise it's homework).

While you're editing that part of your code, also add:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You should add these lines to every Perl program you write and fix all the errors and warnings that they give you.

So what's the problem with this code? I suspect that running it from the browser, you'll get an error about there being no CGI header line. That's because you `exit()` the program from the end of your `table_names()` subroutine. So the program never gets back from calling the `table_names()` subroutine and your main `print()` statement never gets executed - and that includes the `header()`.

Also, in your main `print()` statement, you print the value returned from `table_names()`. But `table_names()` doesn't return anything. You need to change the logic in `table_names()` so that it returns the HTML it creates rather than printing it directly. Printing it directly will put it in the wrong place in the output stream.

One other point that I don't expect you're in any position to do anything about... CGI is pretty much a dead technology. This course is teaching you stuff that would have been useful fifteen years ago. Perhaps you could point your teacher at [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) and ask if he or she would consider teaching something that is more relevant to how web development is done today.

**Update:** The simplest fix is probably to split up your `print` statement so that things happen in the right order.

```
# Print all the start page stuff
print
    header,
    start_html(
        -title => $page1,
        -meta => {
            'viewport'  => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
            'copyright' => 'copyright 2015 Noel Villaman'
        },
        -style => [
            { -src => 'bootstrap.min.css' },
            { -src => 'cgicssjs/style1.css' }
        ]
    ),
    h1( $page1 );

# No need to call print here as table_names
# does its own printing
table_names( $dbh->table_info() );

# Print all the end of page stuff.
print
    hr,
    "\n";
```

You'll still need to remove the `exit()` from the end of `table_names`, otherwise the program will never return from that subroutine.

Also, by doing this you lose a <div> around the output from `table_names`. Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I do not know man. I can run this same subroutine somewhere else, and it works fine. I just think that there something in that I do not see.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure that on its own the subroutine does exactly what you want it to. But when called from within this program it needs to fit in with the way the program works.

Comment: That was the problem, that I was printing something in a print statement. Thanks. This is not for a class, this is for my personal learning.

Comment: Yeah, I know that was the problem. I told you that :-) If this is for your personal study, then you really shouldn't waste your time teaching yourself CGI. Take a look at Mojolicious or Dancer instead.

Comment: I going to take you advice and I will change to one or both of your suggestions. Thanks.